# Referring to Second Last Page in pageref in lastpage package

Tags: hyperref, cross-referencing, lastpage

I can use `\pageref{LastPage}` to give the reference of last page with `lastpage` package. The last page of document is the back cover so I don't want to count it. I wonder how to specify the second last  page with `lastpage` package. Thanks in advance for your help.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use [`refcount`](http://ctan.org/pkg/refcount) to manipulate (page) reference:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lastpage,refcount,atbegshi}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\AtBeginShipout{%
  \ifnum\value{page}=\number\numexpr\getpagerefnumber{LastPage}-2\relax
    \phantomsection\label{preLastPage}
  \fi}
\begin{document}

Last page: \pageref{LastPage} \par
Second to last page: \pageref{preLastPage}

\lipsum[1-50]

\end{document}
```

The reason for comparing `\value{page}` with `<LastPage>-2` is because of the fact that page numbers are stepped *after* printing the value - different from other counters in a document. So, `\AtBeginShipout`, the page counter has already been stepped and we need to insert a `\label` at the end of page `<LastPage>-2` in order for it to be set at the start of page `<LastPage>-1`.

Comment: (+1) Thanks @Werner for your nice answer. It works like a charm except the hyperlink is broken. Any thoughts.

Comment: @MYaseen208 There can be no link if there is no anchor.

Comment: @MYaseen208: I've updated my answer. For future reference, please include a minimal example that shows you're [`hyperref`](http://ctan.org/pkg/hyperref).

Answer (score 5):

The `pageslts` package puts a last page label for each numbering scheme, provided you use a `pagenumbering{…}` at the beginning of the document, and at every scheme change. So, for your cover page, you can use any scheme not used beforehand, setting `\pagestyle{empty}` immediately after:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pageslts,refcount}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage[ plainpages=false, pdfpagelabels=true]{hyperref}

\begin{document}

\pagenumbering{arabic}
Last page: \pageref{pagesLTS.arabic} \par
Very last page:  \lastpageref{LastPages}

\lipsum[1-50]
\clearpage
\pagenumbering{roman}
\pagestyle{empty}
section{New page numbering}
\lipsum[51-60]

\end{document}
```

[image]
Note that the options to `hyperref`are set to prevent any problems if two pages have the same number (even in different numbering schemes), according to the documentation (§ 3.1), but aren't really necessary for the example given here. See the details of constraints in the doc.