# lastpage, hyperref and xifthen

Tags: hyperref, lastpage, xifthen

I am trying to write a code for figuring if the current page is the last page. I do run into some problems, though. In my example here, the code will not run if `hyperref`is loaded. Without it, it produces the result I'm after. Also, in my real document, the code actually works with `hyperref`, although I do not know why. But it does write an extra "page " for some reason. I am not however asking for an explanation of this, as the document is quite complicated at the moment.

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage{lastpage, xifthen,hyperref}
\begin{document}
\ifthenelse{1=\pageref*{LastPage}}{Not last page}{Last page}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got this working with the following code, which is based on Werners response in [this thread](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/195372/referring-to-second-last-page-in-pageref-in-lastpage-package?rq=1)

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage{lastpage,xifthen,hyperref}
\begin{document}
\ifthenelse{\number\numexpr\getpagerefnumber{LastPage}=\thepage}{Last page}{Not last page}
\newpage
\ifthenelse{\number\numexpr\getpagerefnumber{LastPage}=\thepage}{Last page}{Not last page}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to be cautious when working with page-related references. `\pageref*` will not return the last page *number* necessarily. Moreover, a check with `\pageref` might not be expandable, and therefore be useless within the comparison with `\ifthenelse`.

The following implements an automated `\label` with a checking mechanism using [`refcount`](http://ctan.org/pkg/refcount)'s expandable `\getpagerefnumber`:

[image]

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{hyperref,lastpage,refcount}
\usepackage{lipsum}% Just for this example

\newcounter{lastpagecheck}% Counter associated with each \checkiflastpage call
\newcommand{\checkiflastpage}{%
  \stepcounter{lastpagecheck}% Increment lastpagecheck counter
  \label{lpc-\thelastpagecheck}% Mark unique \label
  % Perform expandable check if you're on the LastPage
  \ifnum\getpagerefnumber{lpc-\thelastpagecheck}=\getpagerefnumber{LastPage}
    Last page%
  \else
    Not last page (this page = \pageref{lpc-\thelastpagecheck}; last page = \pageref{LastPage})%
  \fi
}
\begin{document}

\sloppy% Just for this example

\checkiflastpage

\lipsum[1-20]

\checkiflastpage

\end{document}
```

The principle behind this approach, as already mentioned, is to mark the location where the check is performed with a unique `\label` (called `lpc-\thelastpagecheck`, with the aid of a unique counter `lastpagecheck` that is incremented with every call to `\checkiflastpage`).

Since the `\label`-`\ref` system is used with this implementation, you'll have to compile at least twice on the first go to make sure the references settle.

You may have to consider using [`atveryend`](http://ctan.org/pkg/atveryend) to get a proper gauge on the last page in your document, but this really depends on the document construction.

Comment: I saw your response in another thread, and included a working example based on it in my answer. This answer might be better, but I don't know, really. I would like to thank you for two great answers to this question, and I should give you the credit instead of providing an answer myself based on your answer to another question. However, is there anything wrong with doing it that way? I don't really need to know if it actually is the last page, just to know if the document has more than one page.